Web RTC: Remote Video not displaying
The remote video is not being displayed in the remoteVideoEl element, even though the handleTrackEvent function logs the track kind as "video" and successfully adds the track to the remoteStream.The track kind is logged as "video" in handleTrackEvent, indicating a video track is received.The track is added to the remoteStream.However, the remoteVideoEl remains blank, and the remote video is not displayed.
videochat.html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Main" style="height: 100%; background-color: rgb(156, 177, 255)">
      
      <div
        id="video-players-div"
        style="
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
          align-items: center;
          height: 50%;
          background-color:rgb(0, 102, 255);
        "
      >
        <video id="local-video"  style="width: 50%; height: 100%; border: solid white 2px;" autoplay playsinline></video>
        <video id="remote-video" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; border: solid black 2px;" autoplay playsinline></video>
      
      </div>
        <p id="Room-Information" ></p>
        <button id="New-Chat" > New Chat</button>
      
      <div id="user-name"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.5.2/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.7.5/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-2huaZvOR9iDzHqslqwpR87isEmrfxqyWOF7hr7BY6KG0+hVKLoEXMPUJw3ynWuhO" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

client.js
let localStream;
let remoteStream;
let remoteRandomId;
let myPeerConnection;
let roomName;
let offer_;
let answer_;
let randomId;
let didIOffer = false;
const localVideoEl = document.querySelector("#local-video");
const remoteVideoEl = document.querySelector("#remote-video");
const showVideoButton = document.querySelector("#showVideo");

let remoteIceCandidate;

let mediaConstraints = {
  //audio: true,
  video: {
    width: 1080,
    height: 540,
  },
};

if (!window.sessionStorage.getItem("randomId")) {
  randomId = "randomId-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("randomId", randomId);
}

const socket = io.connect(`http://localhost:5010`, {
  auth: {
    randomId: window.sessionStorage.getItem("randomId"),
  },
});

document.getElementById("New-Chat").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(`New-Chat Button Clicked \n`);

  socket.emit("find-partner", {
    randomId: randomId,
  });

  call();
});

socket.on("room-joined", (data) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data), " - data , listening to room-joined event");
  for (const i of data.participants) {
    if (i.randomId !== window.sessionStorage.getItem("randomId")) {
      remoteRandomId = i.randomId;
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("remoteRandomId", remoteRandomId);
    }
  }
  roomName = data.roomName;
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("roomName", roomName);
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("remoteRandomId", remoteRandomId);
});

const call = () => {
  if (myPeerConnection) {
    alert("You cannot start a call because you have got already one open\n");
  } else {
    createPeerConnection();
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
      .then((localStream) => {
        localVideoEl.srcObject = localStream;
        localStream
          .getTracks()
          .forEach((track) => myPeerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`${error} --- error happened while adding tracks \n`);
      });
  }
};

function createPeerConnection() {
  myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: [
      {
        urls: [
          "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
          "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
        ],
      },
    ],
  });

  myPeerConnection.onicecandidate = handleICECandidateEvent;
  myPeerConnection.ontrack = handleTrackEvent;
  myPeerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = handleNegotiationNeededEvent;
  myPeerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange =
    handleICEConnectionStateChangeEvent;
}

   

function handleICECandidateEvent(e) {
  console.log("...Ice candidate found!....");
  console.log(e, " e in handleICECandidate");
  if (e.candiate) {
    socket.emit("new-ice-candidate", {
      target: remoteRandomId,
      candiate: e.candidate,
    });
  }
}

function handleTrackEvent(ev) {
  console.log(`new track coming in , ev -- ${JSON.stringify(ev)}`);
  /*if (ev.streams && ev.streams[0]) {
    remoteVideoEl.srcObject = ev.streams[0];
  } else {
    remoteStream = new MediaStream(ev.track);
    remoteVideoEl.srcObject = remoteStream;
  }*/
  if (!remoteStream) {
    remoteStream = new MediaStream();
  }
  remoteStream.addTrack(ev.track);
  console.log("Track kind:", ev.track.kind); // "audio" or "video"
  remoteVideoEl.srcObject = remoteStream;
}

function handleNegotiationNeededEvent() {
  myPeerConnection.createOffer().then((offer) => {
    offer_ = offer;
    console.log(
      `setting local description as offer --- ${JSON.stringify(offer)} \n`
    );
    return myPeerConnection
      .setLocalDescription(offer)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(
          myPeerConnection.localDescription,
          " localDescription after it was set to offer"
        );
        const msg = {
          randomId: window.sessionStorage.getItem("randomId"),
          remoteRandomId: window.sessionStorage.getItem("remoteRandomId"),
          description: "offer",
          sdp: myPeerConnection.localDescription, //this becomes null, dont know why
        };

        socket.emit("video-offer", msg);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`ran into error when creating offer - ${error}`);
      }); //sdp
  });
}

function handleICEConnectionStateChangeEvent(event) {
  console.log(myPeerConnection.iceConnectionState , "---iceConnectionState---")
  switch (myPeerConnection.iceConnectionState) {
    case "closed":
    case "failed":
      closeVideoCall();
      break;
  }
}

socket.on("video-offer", (data) => {
  //in this case you are the callee....
  console.log(`${JSON.stringify(data)} --- from the caller `);
  if (data.remoteRandomId === window.sessionStorage.getItem("randomId")) {
    //you are the callee

    console.log("call intended for you , you are the callee");

    let remoteRandomId_;
    remoteRandomId_ = data.remoteRandomId;
    createPeerConnection();

    const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp);

    myPeerConnection
      .setRemoteDescription(desc)
      .then(() => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints))
      .then((stream) => {
        localStream = stream;
        localVideoEl.srcObject = localStream;

        localStream
          .getTracks()
          .forEach((track) => myPeerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream));
      })
      .then(() => myPeerConnection.createAnswer())
      .then((answer) => {
        return myPeerConnection
          .setLocalDescription(answer)
          .then(() => {
            console.log(
              myPeerConnection.localDescription,
              " localDescription after it was set to answer "
            );
            const msg = {
              randomId: window.sessionStorage.getItem("randomId"),
              remoteRandomId: window.sessionStorage.getItem("remoteRandomId"),
              description: "answer",
              sdp: myPeerConnection.localDescription, //this becomes null, dont know why
            };

            socket.emit("video-answer", msg);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} ran into some error `));
      });
  }
});

socket.on("video-answer", async (msg) => {
  //in this case you are the caller...
  console.log(`listening to video-answer event -- ${JSON.stringify(msg)}   \n`);
  await myPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(msg.sdp);
});

socket.on("new-ice-candidate", (msg) => {
  console.log(`listening to new-ice-candidate event`);

  handleNewICECandidateMsg(msg);
});

function handleNewICECandidateMsg(msg) {
  /*
    {
      target: remoteRandomId,
      candiate: e.candidate,
    } this is going to be the format of the msg object 
  */

  console.log(msg, `msg inside new-ice-candidate`);
  const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(msg.candidate);
  myPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate).catch((error) => {
    console.log(`${error} happened while adding ice candidates `);
  });
}

main.js (signalling server)
import fs from "fs";
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);

let allUniqueUsers = new Set();
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: [
      
    ],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("find-partner", async (data) => {
    console.log(`listening to the find-partner event  ${JSON.stringify(socket.handshake.auth)}  \n`);
    const allActiveSockets = await io.fetchSockets();

    for (const i of allActiveSockets) {
      console.log(i.handshake.auth.randomId , "randomId in loop" , socket.handshake.auth.randomId , " current random Id")
      if (i.handshake.auth.randomId !== socket.handshake.auth.randomId && socket.inRoom === undefined ) {
        const allRooms = io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
        if (!i.inRoom) {
          createRoom(socket, i);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  socket.on("video-offer" , async (msg) => {
    /*some socket is sending the sdp relay to the receiver ---task 
    
    send it to the callee...*/

    console.log(`listening to video-offer event --- ${JSON.stringify(msg)}`);

    const allActiveSockets = await io.fetchSockets();
    for ( const i of allActiveSockets) {
      console.log(`${i.handshake.auth.randomId} --- randomId in loop ${msg.randomId} -- sender's randomId`)
      if (i.handshake.auth.randomId !== msg.randomId) {
        i.emit("video-offer", msg);
      }
    }
    

  } )


  

  socket.on("new-ice-candidate", async (data) => {

    //where to send this???
    //send the delivered ice candidate information to the target ( also there in the data)

    console.log(`listening to new-ice-candidate event \n`);

    const allActiveSockets = await io.fetchSockets();

    for ( const i of allActiveSockets) {
      if (i.handshake.auth.randomId === data.target) {
           socket.emit("new-ice-candidate", data);
      }
    }
  });

  socket.on("video-answer", async (data) => {
    const allActiveSockets = await io.fetchSockets();
    for (const i of allActiveSockets) {
      if (i.handshake.auth.randomId === data.remoteRandomId) {
        i.emit("video-answer", data);
      }
    }
  });

  

});

function createRoom(callerSocketObject, calleeSocketObject) {
  let currentRandomId = callerSocketObject.handshake.auth.randomId;
  let randomId = calleeSocketObject.handshake.auth.randomId;

  let roomName =
    currentRandomId > randomId
      ? `${currentRandomId}:${randomId}`
      : `${randomId}:${currentRandomId}`;

  callerSocketObject.join(roomName);
  calleeSocketObject.join(roomName);
  callerSocketObject.inRoom = true;
  calleeSocketObject.inRoom = true;

  io.to(roomName).emit("room-joined", {
    roomName: roomName,
    participants: [
      {
        randomId: currentRandomId,
        type: "sender",
      },
      { randomId: randomId, type: "receiver" },
    ],
  });
}

const PORT = 5010;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on port ${PORT} `);
});

